# The well-known 'Docker containers don't see each other' problem

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I checked many forum entries (e.g. in stackoverflow too) but I still cannot figure out what the problem is with my docker-compose file.

So when I start my application (`content-app`) I got the following exception:

```
Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=content-database)(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

My application is a Spring boot app that tries to connect to the database, the JDBC URL is

```
url: jdbc:mariadb://content-database:3306/contentdb?autoReconnect=true
```

The Spring Boot app works fine as locally (when no docker is used) can connect to the local mariadb.
So the `content-app` container don't see the `content-database` container. I read that if I specify a network and I assign the containers to the network then they should be able to connect to each other.

When I connect to the running `content-app` container then I can telnet to  `content-database`

```
root@894628d7bdd9:/# telnet content-database 3306
Trying 172.28.0.3...
Connected to content-database.
Escape character is '^]'.
n
5.5.5-10.4.3-MariaDB-1:10.4.3+maria~bionip/4X@wW/�#_9<b[~)N.:ymysql_native_passwordConnection closed by foreign host.
```

My docker-compose yaml file:

```
version: '3.3'
networks: 
  net_content:
services:
  content-database:
    image: content-database:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./database/Dockerfile 
    networks: 
    - net_content
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  content-redis:
    image: content-redis:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./redis/Dockerfile 
    networks: 
    - net_content
  content-app:
    image: content-app:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./content/Dockerfile 
    networks: 
      - net_content
    depends_on:
    - "content-database"
```

Any hint please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to expose the port on which content-database is listening in the Dockerfile at `./database/Dockerfile`

Comment: Sorry, my fault I forgot to remove the `ports` declaration, it is not in the yaml file.

Comment: So on which port is `content-database` listening? And do you expose that port in the Dockerfile?

Comment: It is the standard 3306. It is exposed there

Comment: Okay, of what kind (driver) is the `net_content`?

Comment: It is a bridge.

Comment: Your network setup looks fine then. And I'm pretty sure that your containers see each other (as you said even the telnet works from one container to the other). Are you sure that you have configured the grants on your database correctly?

Comment: I had to add a `sleep 15` to the `docker-entrypoint.sh` of `content-app`. It seems that the mariadb wasn't ready when the `content-app` tried to connect. Is there any other way to wait for mariadb?

Answer (score 0):

I guess MariaDB is listening on **default port 3307**, this means your application has to connect to this port as well. I guess this is the case as you are mapping the port 3307 of your container to "the outside".

Change the port in your connection string:

```
url: jdbc:mariadb://content-database:3307/contentdb?autoReconnect=true
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault I forgot to remove the `ports` declaration, it is not in the yaml file.